# while reading number greater than 12 digits from excel using c#,number get converted to zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

i'm trying to read a number with length greater than 12 digits from excel file using c# using below query

```
 "select Format([F1], 'Number') as Code";
```

But i get only 12 digits correctly and the rest of the numbers are converted into zeroes.Why is it so??

Example :  `787767786546347` when read from excel file what i get is `787767786546000`

Comment: What type is the c# variable. Is your execel number to big for the desire c# type?

Comment: i'm getting the value into a dataset

Comment: i'm what is the actual value you are getting? perhaps it would be best to show / state that so that others can see what it is you are working with in regards to the 12 digits

Comment: @DJKRAZE added an example

Comment: What kind of a conutry code is `787767786546347`? Do you have integers? Then why use `Format` function with `F1`?

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN:

> Excel follows the IEEE 754 specification on how to store and calculate floating-point numbers. Excel therefore stores only 15 significant digits in a number, and changes digits after the fifteenth place to zeroes.
>
> To work around this behavior, format the cell as text. The cell can then display up to 1,024 characters.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269370

Comment: I understand the question the way, that the excel number is correct but when converting to c# he misses digits.

Comment: ya dats rite but the limit is 15 , but i'm only able to read 12 digits only rest all are zero why so??